# Why the integral symbol is small?

Tags: symbols, eqnarray

I want to write equation with this code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{eqnarray}
        &\dfrac{d\mu(x)}{dx} &= \mu(x)\left(\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}\right)\\
        \iff&\int\dfrac{d\mu(x)}{\mu(x)}&=\int\left(\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}\right)dx
    \end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

[image]
Why the integral symbol is small? How to make it bigger?

EDIT:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        &\dfrac{d\mu(x)}{dx} &= \mu(x)\left(\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}\right)\\
        \iff&\int\dfrac{d\mu(x)}{\mu(x)}&=\int\left(\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}\right)dx
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

If I use align, the result is
[image]

The space before = sign is too long.

Comment: Never use `eqnarray`. It's buggy.

Comment: you are misusing eqnarray, the middle column is supposed to be `&=&`  and set in inline mode. It is best to avoid `eqnarray`, you are loading `amsmath` and can use `align`

Comment: @egreg I remembered well :-) :-) I remembered that `eqnarray` was a depreciated command and created problems.

Comment: If I use ```align```, the space before = sign is too long.

Comment: You are not using the correct number of `&`'s in `align`.  Here there should only be onw `&` per row (`&=`) and I'd use `\iff\quad \int ...`, not need to align there too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `alignat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  && \frac{d\mu(x)}{dx}          &= \mu(x)\left(\frac{x}{1+x^2}\right) \\
\Longleftrightarrow\quad
  && \int\dfrac{d\mu(x)}{\mu(x)} &= \int\left(\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}\right)dx
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Never use `eqnarray`, under any circumstances.

Answer (score 6):

[Don't use eqnarray](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001). Since you load the `amsmath` package anyway, I suggest you use an `align` environment with a single alignment point per row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright}
\mleftright
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    \frac{d\mu(x)}{dx} 
       &= \mu(x)\left(\frac{x}{1+x^2}\right)\\[1ex]
    \iff\int\frac{d\mu(x)}{\mu(x)}
       &=\int\left(\frac{x}{1+x^2}\right)\,dx
\end{align}
\end{document}
```